# PHP Database Class Load Rows function (OOP)

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I want to print out all content of the 'forum_question' table.
What am i doing wrong? No matter what, i will get the message "Nothing found!",
but i am sure the $db->connect DOES work, so it must be something with the query or loadRows functions.

This is my database class:

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $rows;
    private $result;    
    private $dbName;
    private $connection;    
    private $isReady;

    public function __construct() {         
        $this->result = null;
        $this->isReady = false; 
        }

        /* setters */
    public function setHost($host){ $this->host = $host; }
    public function setUser($user){ $this->user = $user; }
    public function setPassword($password){ $this->password = $password; }
    public function setDbName($dbName){ $this->dbName = $dbName; }

    /* Interface functions */
    public function initiate($host=null,$user=null,$password=null,$dbName=null) {
        if(isset($host,$user,$password,$dbName)==false) {
            die("Please provide require settings.");
        }
        $this->setHost($host);
        $this->setUser($user);
        $this->setPassword($password);
        $this->setDbName($dbName);
        $this->isReady = true;
    }

    public function connect() {
        if($this->isReady==false) {
            die("Not ready to connect, please initiate connection");
        }
        $connection_string = "mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->dbName;
        $this->connection = new PDO($connection_string, $this->user, $this->password);
        $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$this->connection); // ensure character/language support
    }   

    public function disconnect() {
        $this->connection = null;
        $this->isReady = false;
        $this->setHost = null;
        $this->setUser = null;
        $this->setPassword = null;
        $this->setDbName = null;
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->result = $this->connection->query($sql);
    }   

    public function countRows() {
        return $this->result->rowCount(); }

    public function loadRows() {
        if(!$this->result) die("Nothing found!");
        $this->rows = array();
        foreach ($this->result as $row) {
            $this->rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $this->rows;
    }

} // End of Database class
?>
```

This is my index file:

```
<?php

require_once 'class_database.php'; 

$db = new Database(); 
$db->initiate("localhost","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE"); 
$db->connect();

$db->query("SELECT * FROM 'forum_question'");
$db->loadRows();


?>
```

Comment: But it seems, the loadRows() function can't find anything, even though i used the query() function?

And how to i exactly do that?

while($query->fetch()) {
row[];
}

like that?

Comment: What does countRows return

Comment: I'm guessing $this->result is false because an error happens. Did you try remove the quotes from forum_question ?

Comment: Yes i removed the quotes, and i don't get the "nothing found" error now.

Comment: and i can run the loadRow() without errors, but how do i actually echo the content of the rows?

Whileloop?

Comment: Yeah.loadRows returns an array

Comment: @Mathias Lynnerup Jakobsen you need to access the data using loop as loadRows() will return you the array...you need to use foreach loop

Comment: Can you help we with a example, on how to use the while loop?

Comment: @aziz-punjani or anyone? Can you guys help me with an example on the while/foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with different connection script? For instance:

```
<?php
$mysql_server = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "USER";
$mysql_password = "PASSWORD";
$mysql_db = "DATABASE";
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s \n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

works fine, all you have to do is:

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'forum_question'";
$mysqli->query($query);
$mysqli->close();
```

Assuming that you saved the connection script in file "connection.php".

Comment: Which code precisely? You can redefine the functions above to work with mysqli.